# How to add custom table in dektrium-yii2-user

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user, yii2-basic-app

I have integrated the dektrium-yii2-user. Now there are profile,social_account,token,user are the tables given by the dektrium.

I need to create a custom table and insert the necessary field that i am needed for my use.

From profile table i need gravatar_email field
from social_account provider and client_id
from user table i need auth_key.

I need to put all these fields in one table and should insert the data in to this table.

Kindly help how to proceed for it.

Comment: what have you tried? Show us what is not working. nobody will just create code for you if you do not show you tried things and got stuck somewhere..

Comment: u are tring to make custom _form.php that will include all those things, am i right?